# Free ATMs in Fuerteventura

Tags: atms, canary-islands

Are there any free cash machines (ATMs) in Fuerteventura? Last time I visited I was charged quite high fees each time I used one, including at the airport.

Comment: Are you sure it's the ATM and not your bank charging the fee?

Comment: @life-on-mars 100% sure yes.  Both cards I use don't normally charge for cash withdrawals in EUR.

Comment: Hmm... can it be that it is a canary island thing? They have for example lower VAT rates than in Spain. Maybe you should ask your bank why a fee was charged.

Comment: @life-on-mars it's exactly as the OP writes. Many times the bank that owns the ATM charges extra fees. Moreover, there are also ATMs not owned by any bank (such as the https://www.euronetatms.com/). In that case, charging extra fees is basically their entire business model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This very recent [forum post](https://www.caminodesantiago.me/community/threads/collecting-a-list-of-cash-machine-atm-fees-in-spain.60486/#post-712030) says iberCaja, Liberbank, UniCaja / EspañaDuero / Kuxtabank ATMs are no fee in Spain. I checked, they are on Fuerteventura as well.

Answer (score 3):

[ATM Fees in Spain](https://www.triptipedia.com/tip/qNefdhY/atm-withdrawal-in-spain-without-fees) says fees can vary depending on:

- the ATM itself (ATMs from a same bank can have different fees)
- the amount withdrawn
- your bank/card

Here are the ranges for each bank:

Kutxabank: no fees
Banca March: no fees
Deutsche Bank: no fees
ING: no fees
Bilbao Bizkaia Kutxa (BBK): no fees
Unicaja Banco: no fees
Eurocaja Rural: no fees
Banco Pichincha: no fees
iberCaja: no fees - €1.75
Bankinter: no fees - €1.75
CaixaBank: no fees - €2.00
Abanca: €0.75 - €0.80
Bankia: €1.75 - €5.00
Sabadell: €1.80 - €5.00
Cajamar: €1.85 - €2.00
BBVA: €1.87 - €7.00
Santander: €2.00 - €8.00